# How to generate a notification in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

I want to build an app which generates a notification (like SMS -> mobile user will get a notification on his or her phone like while reciving a SMS) for a small range of users that are subscribing that notifications.

I have build an App and such a Community Page (I'm not very familar with Facebook).

Here is my code:

```php
//PHP SDK
require 'include/facebook.php';

//Instant Facebook-Object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '...',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $userData = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// If a user haven't been loged in, so the user have to authorize
if (!$user) {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://my-hosting.url/'
            )
    );
    header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
    exit;
}

try {
    $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$testid/feed", 'post', array(
        'message' => 'Hello World',
        'link'  => 'http://www.example.org/',
        'name' => 'Test',
        'description' => 'Wohoo some great text.',
        )
    );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    var_dump($e);   
}
```

I'm playing with the `$testid` it contains e.g. *$user* or *community page ID*.

In case of the user id I get the message on my wall but without any notification with is sad. If I change that to the *community page* I'll get an exception with this message:

> (#210) User not visible

That seems that the community page is not allowed to to that. Well before I try to get that permission I would like to ask if this way is possible or if I'm just wasting my time.

Comment: You want to send a sms? what do you mean by "like sms"?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Good point I want that a mobile user will get a notification on his or her phone like reciving a SMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of mainly two ways of sending notifications to a user using the graph api, each one then splits to two.

1) Requests
The [requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) are a part of the [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) and have two types:

- User requests - will show up in the "globe" notification area on the facebook header.
- App requests - will show up as a counter near the app name in the bookmarks menu

2) Private messages
If you send a private message then the user will get it as any other PM, which means that if the user has installed the facebook app on his mobile phone then he will be notified on the new PM.

You have two ways to send messages using the api:

- [Send dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) - the problem is that you need to use the facebook dialog (using one of their SDKs).
- [The Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) - Using xmpp you can send messages on the behalf of the logged in user. Requires the xmpp_login permission.

Comment: Interesting points. Does I guess right that the *Send Dialog* needs some interactive parts? In my special case that is not possible. About the *The Chat API* do I need to register something? I see that example needs a *userid* must this be a real person or can this be my app or community page?

Comment: It has to be a user, who authorized your app and granted the "xmpp_login" permission. Maybe you can explain what it is exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to build a notification system of events which are generated automatically. Compare it with a monitor system which should inform the current admin of any failure.

Comment: Umm, no, I don't think that it's possible. You'll need to be very creative to pull something like that off, mainly since the facebook api is "user-centric" and your app is not. Seems like the fb graph api is not the right answer for you.

Comment: Well that's a pity. If no one else has better ideas for two days I will accept your answer. Thx +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Notification API for sending the notifications to the registered users.

ref:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/

But I've no idea how can we set the time to send notifications daily.

Comment: Well that looks nice. An other solution would be to send an email to the new `@facebook.com` mail adresses